# Google maps marker title not showing up?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've added a map with a marker to my website but I'm not sure what the Title attribute does for the marker.

I've used the documentation from the developers.google website

> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple

In this example what does the "hello world" (marker title) exactly do?
I am on OS X El Capitan - Chrome

```
function initMap() {
  var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });
}
```

Comment: When you hover on the marker the tooltip will be shown with the title....in ur case 'hello world'.....thats the use of title

Comment: if you hover on the marker you can see the title(hello world).

Comment: That's what I expected but it doesn't seem to be working. Not even on the google site

Comment: @FrankLucas works for me on the Google site.

Comment: @duncan What os and browser are you on?

Comment: @FrankLucas What os and browser are YOU on? Let me guess... IE?

Comment: No I am on OS X ElCapitan - Chrome like I said in OP :)

Answer (score 6):

User @Vijaykrish93 pointed out, that the `title` object in the Marker represents the tooltip value.

For labels the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#marker_labels) has you covered. You just need to set the value for `label` in Marker:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    label: "Hello World!"
});
```

or by using the MarkerLabel interface:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    label: {
        fontSize: "8pt",
        text: "Hello World!"
    }
});
```

More formatting options beside fontSize are described [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#MarkerLabel).

Answer (score 2):

I found it to be unreliable, it wouldn't always show all the title tooltips on mouseover when displaying a group of markers.

The solution is to set this option when creating the Marker:

```
optimized: false
```

*"Optimization renders many markers as a single static element. Optimized rendering is enabled by default. Disable optimized rendering for animated GIFs or PNGs, or when each marker must be rendered as a separate DOM element (advanced usage only)."*

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MarkerOptions

Thanks to the comment here on the Google Maps Issue Tracker for highlighting this solution:
https://issuetracker.google.com/35822066#comment22

Comment: But you should pay attention that this option makes marker "draggable". You can't drag map anymore when starts on marker (marker behaves then as image).

Comment: _this option makes marker "draggable"_ - no, it doesn't.  _"You can't drag map anymore"_  - yes, you can.

Comment: writing "draggable" i meant not the marker itself, but it's image. It's start behaves like typical <img> element - you can drag it around. And about draging map - no, you can't if you try to drag map when mouse down on marker, not map itself. Here's example: http://imgur.com/a/9oYwu

Comment: Ah I didn't fully understand your 2nd point.  In that case, just also set `clickable: false` and then you can.

Comment: With `clickable: false`  the title no longer shows up. And the draggable icon is especially annoying if you're using a sprite for the marker.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you try

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>

function init() {
  var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker , 'click', function(){
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content:'Hello Title',
        position: myLatLng,
      });
      infowindow.open(map);
  });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init()); // two calls

});

</script>
```

you just missed to attach addListener event with marker.